# How to find the x-value given the y-value from a plot in R

Tags: r, plot, label

I am using R 3.4.3, and plotting the following function:

```
x =  rnorm(5000,20,30)
cdf_1 <- ecdf(x)  
plot(cdf_1, xlabs="x0",  
     ylabs="y0")
```

This gives me the following plot:
[image]

Now, the plot doesn't take the given labels x0 and y0. How to solve this?

Also, how do I get the value of x for y=0.95.
I have tried using label names, but it throws error.
Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arguments for the labels are `xlab` and `ylab` (you added an extra `s` in both):

[image]

To find `x` for a `y` of 0.95 you can do:

```
x[which(cdf_1(x) == 0.95)]
#[1] 68.38452
```